# vscode duplicate suggestion type

Tags: visual-studio-code, vscode-snippets

since the last update of vscode `Version : 1.77.0 (user setup)`.

I noticed a duplicate suggestions !?
how i can disable this ? what the keyword in English to search ?
thanks

[image]

Comment: a lot better than no suggestions at all

Answer (score 1):

This suggestions have a different meaning:

```
let a: {fununununnu():void} = {
  // property  - only the property key
  fununununnu
  // method    - method with autocompleted arguments
  fununununnu() {
    
  },
}
```

which are both required in different cases

but they are grouped in the same `(method)` group in `editor.suggest.showMethods` setting and thus can only be disabled both at once

... or both in `(property)` in `let a: {fununununnu:()=>void}` also only at once